# nginx proxy_pass 404 error, don't understand why

Tags: nginx

trying to pass off all calls to /api to my webservice but I keep getting 404s with the following config. Calls to / return index.html as expected. Does anyone know why ?

```
    upstream backend{
server localhost:8080;
}

 server {

        location /api {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        }

        location / {

        root /html/dir;
        }

 }
```

## More info here

```
adept@HogWarts:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ curl -i localhost/api/authentication/check/user/email
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2013 22:49:03 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

adept@HogWarts:/etc/nginx/sites-available$ curl -i localhost:8080/authentication/check/user/email
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2013 22:49:20 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"user":["false"],"emailAddress":["false"]}
```

Comment: location /api {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            }

Needs to be this


    location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend/;
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error 404 returns your backend, he does not know anything about the url /api, which is transferred to it by `proxy_pass` directive.

`curl -i localhost/api/authentication/check/user/email` passed backend as `/api/authentication/...` instead of `/authentication/...`

[If proxy_pass is specified without URI, a request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when processing an original request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Try (note slash / after `backend`)

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://backend/;
}
```